# Dynamic radio VBA

Tags: vba, radio-button

On this internal website it allow me enter a  data and depending on the data the radio box will be enable. How do I know when the radio box is enabled.

Enabled

```
input id="Answer1" name="Answer" type="radio" value="C"
```

Disabled

```
input id="Answer1" name="Answer" disabled="disabled" type="radio" value="C"
```

When it is disabled the getAttribute will return "disabled" but when it is enabled it will return run time error

> Invalid use of Null (Error 94)

if I used

```
msgbox ie.document.all("Answer1").getAttribute("disabled")
```

I tried the following if statement and none will caught it when it is enabled

```
ie.document.all("Answer1").getAttribute("disabled")  = ""
ie.document.all("Answer1").getAttribute("disabled")  = Null
ie.document.all("Answer1").getAttribute("disabled")  <> "disabled"
ie.document.all("Answer1").getAttribute("disabled")  = "disabled"
```

Comment: So you have a visual basic application that has a browser in it? I think it is better to add more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference:[HTML  disabled Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp)

Disabled is a boolean attribute. This means that is value should not be set (e.g. disabled="disabled").  If `disabled` is present then the option is disabled.

```
<option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
```

You should be able to use `msgbox ie.document.all("Answer1").disabled`.  If this doesn't work trap the error

```
Function isDisabled(ele As Object) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
       isDisabled = ele.getAttribute("disabled")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Thanks for showing me trapping the error feature.

Answer (score 0):

I also find this worked too in if statement

`if isnull(ie.document.all("Answer1").disabled) then
 msgbox "Radio box disabled"
else
msgbox "Radio box enabled"
end if`